# FFmpeg API pcm encode without av_interleaved_write_frame

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, encode, pcm

I'm trying encode pcm data use FFmpeg API for livestreaming

like  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041913/android-audiorecord-to-ffmpeg-encode-native-aac)

But it's using "av_interleaved_write_frame".

That's save it in a file by all means.
I want to use it for livestreaming,
I don't want to save it in a file if possible.

And it crashes when I use AVFMT_NOFILE.
It no timestamp when no call "av_interleaved_write_frame",
How can you code it without taking it as a file?